# Permission denied on ionic when saving a file

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a task to download a file from firebase, after i download the file, when i try to save it, it throws me on the console "Permission denied" when i have previously granted permission.

I use *File* and *Filetransfer* for this task, and i have also tried the HTTP native that has a method to "download" files, but im stopped at this point where i have to save the file. Here my code and the console log:

```
getPermission() {
this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(
      (data:any) => {
      if(data.hasPermission) {
         console.log("have permission", data.hasPermission);
         this.guardar(this.imagen);
      } 
   }, (err) => 
 {
   this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
   });
  }
```

This is an image from the console at the moment of saving the image:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of requesting permission, first check if you have Permission and in else block check for permission and further do the operation

```
checkPermission() {
  this.androidPermissions.hasPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    .then(status => {
      if (status.hasPermission) {
        this.downloadFile();
      } 
      else {
        this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
          .then(status => {
            if(status.hasPermission) {
              this.downloadFile();
            }
          });
      }
    });
}
```